# Google Markers setVisible true/false show/hide

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Ok, so I have a google Map store locator. Input a post code, it returns stores in a radius. Got all these pretty info windows, marker icons, and can even do directions...

In a nutshell, I need to be able to HIDE (which I can do) all the markers before I calculate directions (because the directions api seems to automatically add its own markers which I have no idea how to override).

At the moment I'm using the following to HIDE the markers. **This works 100%.** It sets the visible value of the marker to false in the DOM tab of firebug and the marker icons disappear.

```
  function clearMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
```

Now, my issue is I cannot SHOW OR unhide the markers. This is my current function. I can still click on my listing of stores and it pops up the markers infoWindow, BUT the marker just doesn't appear once its been hidden. **Can anyone help me in unhiding the marker ICON in this restoreMarkers function?**

```
  function restoreMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
    markers.setMap(map);
  }
```

[Here's all my code on jsFiddle if you need it](http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/QQKHa/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tried it I can think of one possible thing that could go wrong. Is it possible that the directionsrenderer places another layer on top of the map that hides all the markers? Have you tried removing it to see whether that would bring back the markers?

I have used the setVisible(true) many times without any problems, so if the directionsdisplay is not the problem I am at a loss. Any chance you could link to the homepage where the code runs so we could try it out?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It got me onto the right track. I updated it slightly: http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/QQKHa/2/. The markers show now :) Only problem NOW is that the markers that show when the directions are up don't disappear :(. They also go from green to red after I restore them? o_O. And sorry I can't at the moment :(, the sites not online atm

Comment: You can get the options for the markers using DirectionsRenderer.MarkerOptions and then you can set the visible(false) on them. I believe that should be the way to go :)

Comment: Could it be because when I geocode the address, I run  'createMarker' which adds to the markers array (the red ones), and then google maps overlays green ones? It then removes the green ones, but leaves the red ones? How would I fix that? Only way I can think is that I pass in an extra option, and then delete those markers instead of hide them if they have that option...?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! :) I just modified my createMarker function. `createMarker(destination, null, {isDirection:true,visible:false});` and used jQuery.extend to add visible:false and isDirection:true 1) so I can detect them clear markers and 2) set them as invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Just for everyone's info:

The setMap call at the end of the restoreMarkers function is false! Without verifying, i'd bet this triggered the conflict as the object that shall be set to the map is already there - it's just not visible (imagine of the difference between display:none and visibility:hidden in CSS).

The setVisible method affects only the visibility - not the existence. So setting setVisible to false, will not remove the marker object from the map object, but only makes it invisible.

More information and detailed tutorials about toggling MVC objects and the JavaScript Maps API v3 can be found at my blog. For example check out my latest: https://web.archive.org/web/20111011133754/https://bexton.net/2011/07/11/tutorial-advanced-google-maps-marker-toggle-with-jquery-and-maps-api-v3/